# Загрузить данные из таблицы в другую таблицу: ambiguous column name

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть две таблицы, одну создаем, одна уже существует (`lena.db`). Как загрузить в новую таблицу данные из существующей? Нужно добавить данные одного столбца `UID` в столбец новой таблицы `UID2`.

Делаю так:

```py
cursor.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'lena.db 'AS test")
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM alb JOIN alb5 WHERE UID = ?")
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ambiguous column name: `UID`

Comment: Не забывайте пожалуйста форматировать ваш код.  На плохочитаемый вопрос в один большой абзац никому не приятно отвечать.

Answer (score 1):

У вас по всей видимости в обеих таблицах есть колонка `uid`.
Уточняйте.  Либо:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM alb JOIN alb5
 WHERE alb.uid = ?
```

Либо:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM alb JOIN alb5
 WHERE alb5.uid = ?
```